# Why did Mahadeva help Ashwatthama in his heinous endeavour?

Tags: mahabharata, shiva, punishment, ashwatthama

Ashwatthama entered the Pandava camp in the dead of the night and massacred the mighty warriors when they were asleep. However, initially, he was stopped at the gate and could not enter the camp.

> He there saw a being of huge frame capable of making the very hair erect and endued with the effulgence of the Sun or the Moon, guarding the entrance. - Mahabharata X.6.3

Ashwatthama tried to defeat that being but did not succeed.

> By using my skill and power, I am unable to achieve that which I have promised. Human exertion is never more powerful than destiny. - Mahabharata X.6.25

Then he sought the protection of Mahadeva -

> Armed with a bow, and fingers cased in fences made of iguana skins, Drona's son himself offered up his own self as a victim to Mahadeva. - Mahabharata X.7.51

> Born in Angira's family, I am about to pour my soul, O God, as a libation on his fire. Accept, O Lord, this victim. - Mahabharata X.7.55

At last, Mahadeva appeared in front of him, and entered Ashwatthama's body and also gave him a sword. Then Ashwatthama entered the camp and we know the rest of the story ([Mahabharata X.7](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc825913.html)).

This is very disturbing. Why did Mahadeva help Ashwatthama in this unlawful venture?

> One should not cast weapons against kine, brahmanas, kings, women, friends, one's own mother, one's own preceptor, a weak man, an idiot, a blind man, a sleeping man, a terrified man, one just got up from sleep, an intoxicated person, a lunatic and one that is careless. The ancient preceptors always preached this truth to men. - Mahabharata X.6.21

Why will God help someone do unlawful things? Why would he play the role of a partner in crime? In that case, why would Ashwatthama be called a sinner? Why not Mahadeva?

By the way, my question is **NOT** [how did Ashwatthama invoke Lord Siva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24861/how-did-ashwatthama-pray-to-and-invoke-lord-shiva-on-the-last-night-of-the-war). Instead, I am interested to know why did Siva help him? These are related questions, but not the same.

Comment: Mahadev ji will not judge his disciple. Blessing of Mahadev ji is fundamental to rise of Rakshashas and eventually Ravan whom he refused to kill because his ancestors were given Amaratva vardaan by Mahadev himself! That's he is called Bhola, and that's why Vishnu ji laments that Mahadev ji gives boons to anyone and everyone, then he has to clean up the mess.

Comment: On the contrary, Mahadev ji became furious when he came to know that his devotees ruling Tripur were poisoned in minds using manipulation by Devtas in order to destroy their great world. The Pashu in each of them devtas including Vishnu became the constituent of Pashupateyastra, which destroyed the Tripura finally.

Comment: There time on earth was over so up til that shiva acted as proctor but after that he assumed the form of destroyer -  Mahadeva said
"The period of their lives hath run out" - You can find the answer here. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24862/5620